# Storing CocoaPods libraries in own Git repository

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Usually we don't store CocoaPods libraries on our Git repositories. Though sometimes it can be a good option if someday you figure out that there are no Git repositories of some libraries. What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: [Cocoapods Podfile guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify different paths or Git URLs to the pods in your Podfile. So you can fork the repositories of the pods in question on GitHub (or host them on your own Git server) and then change the URLs in the Podfile like this:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git'
```

or:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :path => '~/Documents/AFNetworking'
```

See [The Cocoapods Podfile guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo) for more information.